# Schedule class runs instantly

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I have a controller of an Apex Page from where I am calling a schedule apex class using system.schedule to run after one hour. From that schedule class, a batch class is being called to run which has email sending functionality.

Ideally, I am expecting those emails to be received one hour after my operation in controller.

Though I find a schedule job being created at the perfect time, the emails are received instantly after the schedule class called from controller.

Can someone please help me figure out the issue?

**Controller code**

```
 BatchScheduleUpdate bcn = new BatchScheduleUpdate (selcall[0]) ;
                    String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour() + 1);
                    String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute()); 
                    String ss = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());
                    String nextFireTime = ss + ' ' + min + ' ' + hour + ' * * ?';
                    System.schedule('Job Started At ' + String.valueOf(Datetime.now()), nextFireTime, bcn);
```

**Schedule Class:**

```
global class BatchScheduleUpdate implements Schedulable
{   private Call__c modCall;

 global BatchScheduleUpdate (Call__c modCall) {
        modCall = modCall;
    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {   
        if(modcall!=null)
       { Notbatch b = new Notbatch (modCall);
         database.executebatch(b);
       }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class will fail if current hour value is 12, than it will equal to 13 and fail to schedule class.

Try to set scheduler like this:

```
Datetime fireTime = Datetime.now().addHours(1);
String cron = fireTime.second() + ' ' + fireTime.minute() + ' ' + fireTime.hour() + ' * * ?';
System.schedule('Test schedule run', cron, new BatchScheduleUpdate());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why is it instantly running the emails? I need to run them 24 hours after. Also, I am getting this compile error.   Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addHour(Integer) from the type Datetime at line ....

Comment: @Testing_SFDC ```addHours()``` my mistake, sorry. That can be explained if you have mismatch in timezone on your machine and timezone set in your org or user.